# Android - How to stop showing notification when open application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm new to android development... trying to build application which send notification at specific time daily.First time if I tap on notification it opens application and notification doesn't come again. But after that **if I open application it shows notification again.. how to stop showing it again? but show only at particular time?**
..

**MainAcitivty code is:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 36);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i.getBooleanExtra("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER", false)) {
            pendingIntent.cancel();
        }
    }
```

**AlarmReceiver Class is :**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER", true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText("notification text")
                .setContentTitle("notification title")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(true);
        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: I think you have to Run am.setRepeating for one time . Dont write it on onCreate .

Comment: probably that was because i restart my phone.. so i remove that line from my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main Activity look like this:-

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 49);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

        if(calendar.getTimeInMillis()>System.currentTimeMillis()){

             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
             pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
             AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
             am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent); //Repeat every 24 h


         }
        else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Always set value with greater than current time",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




    }
}
```

and put below code on your reciever:-

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER", true);
    context.startActivity(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText("notification text")
            .setContentTitle("notification title")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true);
    notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
```